# WordPress query slow with many posts and custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, vps

I have a WordPress site with around 350K rows in the posts table and 4.5M postmeta rows. It is mainly used for editing and archiving in the backend with no frontend traffic, and it is hosted on a Ubuntu VPS with 8GB memory and 4 virtual CPUs and SSD disk.

Everything is running pretty nice and fast both on the frontend (using the TwentyFifteen theme) exception made for the post editor. Just opening a post in the backend takes around 12 seconds. Query monitor shows up a slow query taking 11,7 seconds to perform at database level:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_key 
FROM wp_postmeta 
LIMIT 0,1000

meta_form() wp-admin/includes/template.php:632
post_custom_meta_box() wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php:637
do_meta_boxes() wp-admin/includes/template.php:1073
```

It looks like the mysql database is properly configured using the Percona database config tool to use most of the VPS resources.

Post updates and new post are slow as well. Any tip?

Comment: Is there an index over `(meta_key)` in `wp_postmeta`?

Comment: I'm not sure but here's my table structure [link]https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM3GZAQzl6KqhMDtZvT28N3B170PQ7pGZBGWL6v3cMA_zP0y7I-CVxh8Y6uBY5OjA?key=WXVHUldzalJNRW1VZjZvU3VpMzRhVVhodHV1TENB[/link]

Comment: In that case, yes there is such an index.  Could you please try prepending `EXPLAIN` to that query and showing us the output?

Comment: I wanted to update the question with a solution. It turned out that the meta_key field in the post_meta table was set to VARCHAR(255) while the index was at 191. Setting the field type to VARCHAR(191) solved the issue and the total query time is now under 0,2 seconds